# Remove all duplicated lines based on first column

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file :

```
AX-172321889 4
AX-172321889 4
AX-172322243 2
AX-172322331 2
AX-172322347 2
AX-172322347 2
AX-172322347 2
AX-172322354 2
AX-172322383 2
AX-172322440 2
AX-172322719 7
```

I need to remove **every** duplicated or more lines. And not keeping one occurence for each of them. I know :

`awk '!seen[$1]++'` or `sort -t'-' -k1,2n | uniq` is pretty close of what I want, but this keeps one occurence.

I should get :

```
AX-172322243 2
AX-172322331 2
AX-172322354 2
AX-172322383 2
AX-172322440 2
AX-172322719 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU uniq):

```
uniq -u file
```

Or if it just the first field use:

```
uniq -uw 12 file
```

Belt and braces:

```
sort file | uniq -uw 12
```

A GNU sed solution:

```
sed -E 'H;$!d;x;s/(\n\S+ )\S+(\1\S+)+//g;s/.//' file
```

Comment: Pretty simple actually, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A working `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{++freq[$1]; rec[$1] = $0}
END {for (f in freq) if (freq[f] == 1) print rec[f]}' file

AX-172322440 2
AX-172322354 2
AX-172322383 2
AX-172322243 2
AX-172322719 7
AX-172322331 2
```

If you want sorted values in output then you may use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{++freq[$1]; rec[$1] = $0} 
END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
for (f in freq) if (freq[f] == 1) print rec[f]}' file

AX-172322243 2
AX-172322331 2
AX-172322354 2
AX-172322383 2
AX-172322440 2
AX-172322719 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your key values are grouped together like in the example you provided (if not, sort the input first):

```
$ awk '
    $1 != p1 { if (cnt==1) print p0; cnt=0 }
    { ++cnt; p1=$1; p0=$0 }
    END { if (cnt==1) print p0 }
' file
AX-172322243 2
AX-172322331 2
AX-172322354 2
AX-172322383 2
AX-172322440 2
AX-172322719 7
```